# Assigning a string to a text value in an async task called from AppWidgetProvider

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-widget, android-xml

I am trying to set a textview value in a widget via an async task. I created a simple widget whose layout looks like this:

widget_test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/widget_bg_normal"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="testing 123"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        >
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My AppWidgetProvider code is:

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 12/26/13.
 */
public class HelloWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(Context context){

        //build url for async task
        String url = "hiddenURL";

        //call async task
        new GetRandomBeer(context).execute(url);



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds){

        //todo: call update code, which should be the same as onEnabled


    }


}
```

This above code should control what happens when the app is enabled (aka when user adds the app to their home screen) and what the app should do when it updates itself based on the time set in my hello_widget-provider.xml here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="146dip"
    android:minHeight="72dip"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_test"
    >

</appwidget-provider>
```

For testing purposes I am not having my asynctask parse any json yet I am just trying to change the value of the text on my widget via the async task. Here is the code for my async task:

```
package com.example.beerportfoliopro;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro.R;

public class GetRandomBeer extends AsyncTask
        <String, Void, String> {

    Context c;

    public GetRandomBeer(Context context)
    {
        c = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }



    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Log.d("taste","Inside get taste");
        //decode json here
        try{

            //todo: get all beer data



            //todo: set text views with data
            TextView breweryTitle = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.widget_tv);




        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }


    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

My problem right now is that right now my widget_tv is showing the error:

```
cannot resolve symbol widget_tv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TextView ID should be: `R.id.widget_tv` not `R.widget_tv`

Comment: Dumb mistake...Thanks. I will accept your answer once it allows me to in a few minutes. Now I am trying to figure out why this wont change the text view value when it is added the the home screen. But I will open a separate question for that if your interested.

Comment: @Mike Yes please do, I will try to look into it.

Comment: here is my next question, thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792944/appwidgetprovider-public-void-onenabled-context-context-does-not-effect-widget

Answer (score 1):

have you called setContentView(view) in the activity class that you are passing to the asynctask before executing the asynctask? if not you should use the layout inflater to inflate the textview

```
((Activity) c).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.widget_tv, null);
```

Comment: I know the text view is there because it says testing 123. If you want you can check out my new issue here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20792944/appwidgetprovider-public-void-onenabled-context-context-does-not-effect-widget